# Bing Maps in Ionic v1 Framework is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, bing-maps

I am trying to use Bing maps API in ionic v1 framework app which builds on android,iOS and windows platforms.

I am facing problem in Bing maps which is plotting properly but **zoom in,zoom out,changing the map type from aerial to road & fetching current location these buttons are not functional**.I have proper API key to access maps. I even tried it doing **ionic serve** on browser but nothing helped me.

I have followed code from the below link:
https://github.com/eppineda/ionic.bing-map-demo

I have also changed JS src file of bing maps in index.html page from:
**src='http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0'**

To

**src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol'**

The src file i have changed referring to Microsoft document pages as below:
**http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#loadMapAsync+HTML**

Issue can be seen in the link - 
**http://plnkr.co/edit/NO5eLxogOyPHsiXzzpaQ?p=preview**

```
$scope.init = function () {
  console.log('Map init');

  var mapOptions = {
    credentials: '',
    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.5033640, -0.1276250),
    zoom: 15,
    // showLocateMeButton: false,
    // // NavigationBarMode: "default",
    // // NavigationBarOrientation: "vertical",
    // showZoomButtons: false,
    // ShowNavigationBar: false
    showDashboard: true
    // // showMapTypeSelector : true
    // // showMapTypeSelector: false
    // navigationBarMode: Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode.compact

  };
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMap'), mapOptions);
  console.log(map);

};
```

Please help me out to figure this out.It would be really helpful with the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information. The new map URL you are saying you are using doesn't have a callback parameter in it, so that doesn't align with the async sample you pointed to. Is the map loading up and you can see the navigation bar? Is the issue mainly with interacting with the map? Does panning work? Can you provide any code?

Comment: As i am running it on ionic,i am initialing map using controller once **deviceready** function is called.I am able to see navigation bar with location,zoom in and zoom out buttons but these are not functional.

Comment: Below is my controller code: 
$scope.init = function () { console.log('Map init'); var mapOptions = { credentials: 'my api key here', mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.5033640, -0.1276250), zoom: 15 } map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMap'), mapOptions); };

Comment: Are you able to move the map with touch/pinch?

Comment: Yes i am able to do pinch zoom and pan around maps.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is one of two issues. The first is that you have some other HTML element above the map and/or navigation bar/buttons. This would block you from being able to press those buttons. The second is that your code is actually loading the map twice somehow and as such you are ending with two maps on top of each other. When this happens the navigation bar for the bottom map ends up on top and using it actually changes the bottom hidden map. I've seen this occur once before in someone else's app who load the map twice to the same div.

Comment: I am using ionic framework probably that is wrapping functionality of map not sure. I am not getting any reply from ionic people.

Comment: Is there any way to check if my map is painted twice ?

Comment: As a quick and dirty check, add an alert where the map load code is. If the alert is fired twice, then the map load function is being called twice somewhere.

Comment: My map gets initialized only once has i had put console to check the way you had said.

Comment: Not sure then. Just downloaded the sample you pointed to on GitHub, updated the map script URL and it just worked.

Comment: That is not working the way ionic does he is loading maps in index.html file where i am trying to load maps from controller.So,it doesnt work for me.

Comment: The example i was facing issue posted in below link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NO5eLxogOyPHsiXzzpaQ?p=preview

Comment: Looks to be an ionic browser support issue. When I try in edge, the buttons work, but the mouse can't pan/zoom. In chrome, the buttons don't work, but the panning and zooming does. Touch works fine in both. Still don't know what to tell you. Know several others using Ionic and never came across this issue before. Looking into this it looks like Ionic is overloading the map with CSS. I recommend going through and disabling it one by one in a browser using dev tools (F12) until it works.

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the issue but dint help this way by disabling css one by one through browser.

Comment: any solutions or suggestions people ? stuck with this thing from couple of days.

Comment: I was able to check in IE it was working fine but in Google chrome,android and iOS it was not working fine.Issue still exist.